# The current type, is an interface and cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I'm just starting to work with Unity as DependencyInjector.
I have always used Windsor Castle.

I'm trying to do the following.
In my global.asax I have the following code:

```
DIContainerConfig.RegisterDependencies();
```

In my DIContainerConfig, I have the following code:

```
 internal static void RegisterDependencies()
{
    //Initialize IoC container/Unity
    ManagerInstaller.Initialise();
    RepositoryInstaller.Initialise();

    //Register our custom controller factory
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(ControllerInstaller));

}
```

My RepositoryInstaller looks as follows:

```
public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
{
    var container = BuildUnityContainer();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    return container;
}
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IStudentsRepository, StudentsRepository>();
    MvcUnityContainer.Container = container;
    return container;
}
```

And my ControllerInstaller:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    try
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerType");

        if (!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Type requested is not a controller: {0}",
                controllerType.Name),
                "controllerType");

        return MvcUnityContainer.Container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now when I debug the application, I'm getting into the controller installer, but I'm getting the error:

> The current type, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

What am I doing wrong?

I get the error on this line:
return MvcUnityContainer.Container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;

This is the stacktrace:

[InvalidOperationException: The IControllerFactory 'Latin.Configuration.Installers.ControllerInstaller' did not return a controller for the name 'Students'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +331
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +72
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +30
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Somewhere you are apparently asking for "Student" controller which is not found or not registered as a controller. Tried your sample with Unity and with this text in `Index.cshtml` I am table to reproduce error: `@Html.Action("Index", "Student")`. This way Student controller is not found, and I get the same error.

Comment: @Jure: that is indeed what I am doing. How can I resolve this issue then?

Comment: I removed the @Html.Action("Index", "Student") but i still get the same error.

Comment: Either implement StudentController or remove all references to it. Try to find "Student" within entire solution, to find out where it is used and if it's used in the right way.

Comment: I have a studentcontroller. So it is strange that it would give a problem.

Comment: Then I would guess you have a typo somewhere, since the error says: controller for the name 'Students', that would mean you have `StudentsController`, while controller name is actually `StudentController` - without `s`.

Comment: Thx for your help. I'll keep looking for the error in my code.

Comment: Still getting the same error: {"The current type, Latin.Domain.Interfaces.IStudentsRepository, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97548/discussion-between-jure-and-bart-schelkens).